# Extra white space at bottom of UIScrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

My Scroll View is pinned to the safe area on all 4 sides and is the size of the screen. I pinned the content view (view inside scroll view) to the content layout guide of the scroll view. And all my UI elements in the view are constrained properly so scroll view height ambiguity is not an issue. However the user can scroll down the continue button, and I don't know how to solve this issue.

This is the error I'm having:
[Image for Extra space beneath content view inside scroll view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw7aZ.png)

[Another image. This causes white space beneath the blue view as so, I want the user to not be able to scroll past the blue view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmrKx.png)

Comment: Are you using the Storyboard to layout your views? Or are you doing it programmatically?

Comment: Using Stodyboard, the first picture shows the storyboard

Comment: 1. Do you need the Continue button to be within the scroll view and hence scrollable? Or do you need it to be fixed in place?
2. Do you want to make it such that the continue button is at the very bottom, without anything else visible beneath it?

Comment: Is the "white space beneath the blue view" the view controller's view? Or is it the scrollview? Is your scrollview constrained to safe-area or all the way to the edges?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh Thank you for helping. I want to make the button at the very bottom. Right now it's at the very bottom of the content view.

Comment: @DonMag, thank you as well. It is the scrollview, I think I might of constrained the bottom of my scroll view to the superview as opposed to the safe area. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @PraneetKedari make sure the Continue button and blue view are not inside the scroll view. Then constrain the blue view to the main view's bottom constraint, while the scroll view's bottom constraint should be constrained to the blue view's top constraint

Comment: @SylvanDAsh that makes so much sense, thank you!! I will let you know if that works

Comment: That worked @SylvanDAsh!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

To make the button be fixed at the bottom of the view, then:

- make sure the continue button and blue view are not inside the scroll view
- constrain the blue view to the main view's bottom constraint
- constrain the scroll view's bottom constraint to the top of the blue view

This way, the button will remain fixed, while the content within the scroll view will still be scrollable